# Can't access lazy annotated but initialized hibernate collection from JSF2

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I have a many-to-many relationship between the two entities called events and artists, both are annotated to be lazy loaded. When I load an artist, I initialize its events because the session will be closed afterwards using

```
Hibernate.initialize(artist.getEvents());
```

A test in pure Java works fine and I can access the events and its properties afterwards.

But in the .xhtml page presenting the result, I can only access the artist's properties and test if there are any events available, Artist is the backing bean, getData() returns the Artist, the following line still works:

```
<h:outputText value="No events available" rendered="#{empty artist.data.events}"/>
```

But when I want to access the properties of the events in a dataTable using

```
<h:dataTable value="#{artist.data.events}" var="event" rendered="#{not empty artist.data.events}">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{event.title}"/>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I get the followig exception:

```
/artist.xhtml @48,63 value="#{event.title}": The class 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'title'.
```

My first thought was that Hibernate's initialize method does not work together with JSF2, but event when I change the FetchType from LAZY to EAGER I end up getting the same result.

The Event class looks like this, for brevity I only included the parts relevant to the title property:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="Events")
@SequenceGenerator(name="events_id", sequenceName="event_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class EventData implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    // other private variables

    public EventData() {}

    public EventData(String title, ...) {
        this.title = title;
        // ...
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    // other setters/getters, equals/getHashCode overrides    

}
```

Comment: Can u post the code of the the class "Event"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIData` components can only iterate over an [`T[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), [`List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a [`DataModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html), not over a [`Set<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) because there's **no way** to identify an element in a `Set<E>` by an **index**, while it is required in `UIData` components.

[@Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) has written a [weblog](http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/how-to-iterate-over-javautilset-in-jsf/) describing one way how to go around it. Other ways are to configure JPA to use `List<E>` instead or to add a getter which wraps it in a `List<E>` or `DataModel<E>` and use it instead in `UIData` component. E.g.

```
public DataModel<Event> getEventModel() {
    return new ArrayDataModel<Event>(events.toArray(new Event[events.size()]));
}
```

This by the way uses the *same* instances (doesn't copy/clone/recreate them), so all changes will be reflected in the right instances.

---

**Update**: in the upcoming JSF 2.2, the `UIData` will finally [support](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-479) [`Collection<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), which thus includes `Set<E>`. Another way is to create a custom EL resolver as answered here: [How do I use a java.util.Set with UIData in JSF. Specifically h:datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327479/how-do-i-use-a-java-util-set-with-uidata-in-jsf-specifically-hdatatable/9327572#9327572)

Comment: thanks for the exact answer BalusC, after I added a property events (List<EventData> getEvents()) to my Artist backing Bean it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Voodoo is required to expose any bean to the #{...} facility.  The simplest is to use CDI if your web container supports it, but otherwise look at the @ManagedBean annotation in JSF2.

Comment: I have other xhtml pages accessing the Artist's properties just fine which is a @ManagedBean