# ui:repeat inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat

I have this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{orderController.listRequestItem}" var="item">
....
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>#{item.product.codigoProduto}</td>
  <td>
    <ui:repeat value="#{item.product.materials}" var="m">
     #{m.description}
    </ui:repeat>
  </td>
...
```

The `listRequestItem` is:

```
public List<RequestItemVO> listRequestItem;
```

and here I'm populating it:

```
listRequestItem = new ArrayList<>(requestVO1.getRequestItem());
```

The `item.product.materials` is:

```
public Set<MaterialVO> getMaterials()
{
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
```

When I try to access the `m` on my inner `<ui:repeat>`, I can't access its methods.

The `#{item.product.codigoProduto}` is returning the product code correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<ui:repeat>` doesn't support `Set<E>`. This support will be [introduced](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#479) in the upcoming JSF 2.2 (also for `<h:dataTable>`). JSF 2.2 will be released this quarter already.

In the meanwhile, you need to convert it to `List`. There are several ways:

- Change the property to be `List<MaterialVO>` instead and alter business code accordingly.

  ```
  private List<MaterialVO> materials;
  ```
- Or add a wrapper property and use it instead.

  ```
  public List<MaterialVO> getMaterialList() {
      return new ArrayList<MaterialVO>(materials);
  }
  ```

  This is only expensive as the getter is invoked on every iteration. You may want to add another property which wraps the original set.
- Or create a custom EL function which does the job:

  ```
  <ui:repeat value="#{util:setToList(item.product.materials)}" ...>
  ```
- Or create a custom EL resolver. Detail can be found in this answer: [How do I use a java.util.Set with UIData in JSF. Specifically h:datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327479/how-do-i-use-a-java-util-set-with-uidata-in-jsf-specifically-hdatatable/9327572#9327572)

This problem is not related to nesting `<ui:repeat>`.